# Python: UTF-8 Hex to UTF-16 Decimal

Tags: python, utf-8, hex

I got a chinese han-character 'alkane' (U+70F7) which has 
an UTF-8 (hex) - Representation of 0xE7 0x83 0xB7 (e783b7).
(See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/70f7/index.htm)

**I need to convert this string of 'e783b7' to the decimal value of 28.919 (UTF-16 decimal).**

As I am pottering on this problem one hour now I think it's faster to ask on stackoverflow

Thanks a lot

Dr. Cobra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ord` builtin function, like this:

```
>>> print('\u70f7')
烷
>>> print(ord('\u70f7'))
28919
```

If you only have a hex-string (works in Python 2 and 3):

```
>>> s = bytearray.fromhex('e783b7').decode('utf-8')
>>> s
u'\u70f7'
>>> print(s)
烷
```

Comment: just python3 i guess?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use Python 2 today, but prefixing the unicode string with `u` makes it work there too.

Comment: nice, work as a charm. And as python2, sadly is the standard in vfx bussiness actually. So, yeah, lot of people sticked to python 2 mate.

Comment: @DanielSanchez standard soon going to change better be prepared; python 2 end of support is 2020 ... I'm fighting in my place already for a while and push for python 3 whenever it's possible and do v2 only when supporting existing code base and still - try to convert to v3 as much as possible :)

Comment: @Drako, exactly, im fighting for it here too, we are writting tons of code that would be deprecated shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. And how do I get from utf-8 hex of "e783b7" to the unicode description of '\u70f7'? The problem is, that the repr()-function of these chinese sign only gives me the utf-8 hex "e783b7".

Comment: Great! Works fine! Thanks a lot